# weird CSS problem? positioning div elements using float property

Tags: css, html, positioning, css-float

In dreamweaver when I enter this html:

```
<div style="float:left;width:100px;height:20px">a</div>
<div style="float:left;clear:left;width:100px;height:100px">b</div>
<div style="float:left;width:80px;height:100px">c</div>
```

div c appears to be aligned to the top along side the top of div a. This is how I want it
to display, however when rendered in a browser (firefox, ie tested) div c is below div a and aligned to div b instead. How can I fix this?

Comment: Never trust Dreamweaver's live view, ever. Even with simple HTML tables it screws up the rendering, always check in a browser, always!

Comment: As Kyle Sevenoaks said, the problem is in Dreamweaver. From CSS point of view, the browsers show it how it's supposed to render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Dreamweaver.

Elements do not float up past a clearing element in the same context.

It sounds like you want:

```
<div style="width: 100px; float: left;">
    <div style="height:20px">a</div>
    <div style="height:100px">b</div>
</div>
<div style="float: left;width:80px;height:100px">c</div>
```

Comment: Hey, this puts all the divs in one column, I need div c to be next to div a on the right side so the letter c is aligned with the letter a, and b is below a.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to guess the layout you want from your description:

Try this and let me know...

```
<div style="float:left;width:100px;height:20px">a</div>   
<div style="float:left;width:80px;height:100px">c</div>
<div style="clear:both;width:100px;height:100px">b</div>
```

Comment: Actually sorry no, I responded too fast. The div b element should be directly under a

Comment: I see a         c on the first line and then there is a gap of 100 pix and then the second line starts with b

Comment: So you have b directly under a. How should they appear?